# Merging the List, Show, New and Edit actions of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new in Rails.
I want a Simple Example in Rails 3 with only one index.html.erb file with All Actions merged including New, listing, Show , Edit (e.g all Actions) and If Example with Relationship of 1-to-Many will be perfect for me.
Take Example as **Purchase Order(PO_Num, Date) has many Products(Name, Qty, Price)**

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to merge the templates for all of the actions into one template? They're all conceptually quite different views, so having separate templates is normally a good idea. If you have shared code between them, there are better ways of achieving this (eg using partials or helpers).

If you really want to override a template used in an action, you can just call the render method:

```
def show
   render "index"
end
```

Comment: Actually I have seen same action is performed in one on the Video by Lynda.com . Where they have merged all actions into one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for action_name in the view:

```
<% case action_name %>
<% when 'index' %>
... view part for index action here
<% when 'show' %>
... view part for show action here
<% when 'new' %>
... view part for new action here
<% when 'edit' %>
... view part for edit action here
<% end %>
```